# Creating a custom Multi-Friend Selector using the PHP-SDK and JS-SDK

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I am having trouble creating a working Multi Friend Selector.

Here is what I have so far...

This Loads my facebook SDK and the function "sendRequest" which is what I need to call to send the dialog request.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    // init the FB-JS-SDK
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'APP_ID', // App ID from the App Dashboard
            status: true, // check the login status upon init?
            cookie: true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
        });

        // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
    };

    function sendRequest(userid) {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'Check out this application!',
            to: userid,
            title: 'Test request',
        });
        return false;
    }

      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Here is my simple form, I use PHP to create the list of friends. This part works fine...

```
<form name="start_trial_form" method="POST" action="index.php">
<?php 
foreach ($usr_friends['data'] as $friend) {
    echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="sendto_id" value="'.$friend['id'].'"/> <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $friend['id'] . '/picture" title="' . $friend['name'] . '"/>' . $friend['name'] . '</label>';
}
?>
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="title"/>
<textarea name="text"></textarea>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is the if statment that runs after the form is submitted. My problem is that when I try to run sendRequest from here nothing happens... If I put -> onlick="sendRequest('someid#')" within the submit button it works just fine. So my problem must be within the way I am calling this function. I'm alot more comfortable with PHP then JS.

```
<?php 

    if (!empty($_POST['sendto_id'])) {
        ?>
        <script> sendRequest(<?php echo $_POST['sendto_id']; ?>);</script>
        <?php 
        // some more code
    }
?>
```

Can someone please explain to me why this is not working?

Comment: Do you even have the function declaration for `sendRequest` embedded into the page that handles the submitted form data?

Comment: @CBroe The declaration is in the first snippet of code on line 15. I then call the function in the third snippet of code like this > `<script> sendRequest(<?php echo $_POST['sendto_id']; ?>);</script>` is that not the correct way to call a function?

Comment: Are both snippets in the same HTML document, that the client gets send after he submits the form? Is the JS SDK already properly initialized at the point you are trying to call this function? (If you are calling it straight away by just outputting the script element, then it probably isn’t. Anyway, you browser’s error console should be able to tell you that, so please make use of it!)

Comment: @CBroe Yes, currently they are all in the same document. I believe it is because I can get it working with the onclick= and manually passing an id.